# Testing view rendering with mock objects in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I have a controller action that calls a model that fetches a JSON object from a web service. The JSON object is converted to a PHP object via a mapper class and used in my view.

What I'd like to do is to write a unit test that mocks the web service response, calls my mapper class to map the response to my PHP object and then uses that object in my view. This way, I can use `assertQueryContentContains()` to check to see if the values are being properly mapped to my object and populated in my view.

What is the best way to do this?

So far, I've got this in my unit test class:

```
$view->search_session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('search');

Zend_Registry::set('is_mobile', false);

$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/scripts/');
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers');

$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts/')->setLayout('layout-internal');

$layout->setView($view);

$mapper = new ListingDetailMapper();
$listing = $mapper->map($this->_createMockListing(), new ListingDetail());

$view->listing = $listing;

$this->getResponse()->setBody($layout->render());

$this->assertQueryContentContains('h3.fn', 'Test Business');
```

The problem that I have with this is that I'm having to setup everything manually that would normally be setup in my bootstrap or configuration file if I were to dispatch the request normally.

Is there a way to inject my mock object into my view, so I can render the view automatically as it would if I dispatched the controller action using `$this->dispatch()`?

Or, should I somehow be mocking the model class that would normally return the web service response and somehow inject that into my controller?

It seems like I'm working a little too hard by having to recreate my environment as if I had called `$this->dispatch()`. Plus, it kind of defeats the purpose of testing if you aren't using the same setup code as you would in a real environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decide what type of test this is. Right now it's trying to be a unit test. From reading what you say in your question,

> it kind of defeats the purpose of testing if you aren't using the same setup code as you would in a real environment

it sounds like you want to be doing a system test.

If you want to do a system test then start using use dispatch() fully. You will have to automate your database/datastore to import and remove test data at the same time.

If you are trying to do a unit test then your view script is making it hard for you. The view script should not really be aware of the layout. If you can fix that then you can clean that code up. Your view script should not be aware of Zend_Registry. Don't forget Zend_Registry is just a global variable hiding behind a pattern name. I would also say it should not be aware of Zend_Session. Any of the data these classes provide should be either set by the controller or in a view helper. If you can fix those you can clean up that code.

There is also a fundamental principle to keep in mind, that the more dependencies a piece of code has, the more work it will be to set up testing for it. Right now your view script has a lot of dependencies and that is why it is more work to unit test it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You've answered other questions of mine, and as usual, you've been a huge help. You're absolutely right about the view being aware of things it shouldn't be. I've re-factored some things, taking into account your suggestions. The reference to the registry was in the layout and it turns out that I didn't need to instantiate the layout at all to test the view. Allowing the controller to handle the session stuff meant, in my unit test, I could just set a view variable to represent what should be there. In the end, I wound up with a much simpler test. Thanks again.

Comment: Anyone trying to tests there code is a friend of mine ;) . I'm glad to help, I've learned this all the hard was so I'm just trying to spread the automated testing love.